# Cert fails in type-orm but works fine with node-postgres

Tags: amazon-iam, typeorm

I want to connect to a Postgres data source using `type-orm` like this:

```js
it("can connect using type-orm", async () => {
    const signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer({
        region: REGION,
        hostname: DB_INSTANCE,
        port: DB_PORT,
        username: DB_USER
    })

    const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
        type: "postgres",
        host: DB_HOST,
        port: DB_PORT,
        username: DB_USER,
        password: async () => signer.getAuthToken({}),
        database: DB_DATABASE,
        entities: [],
        synchronize: false,
        logging: false,
        ssl: {
            ca: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem').toString(),
        },
    })

    await AppDataSource.initialize()
});
```

But it fails with:

> Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: localhost. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS: <TRUE AWS altnames here>

What is interesting is that the exact same credentials/certificate works fine with `node-postgres`:

```js
it("can connect using node-postgres", async () => {
    const signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer({
        region: REGION,
        hostname: DB_INSTANCE,
        port: DB_PORT,
        username: DB_USER
    })

    const client = new Client({
        user: DB_USER,
        host: DB_HOST,
        database: DB_DATABASE,
        password: signer.getAuthToken({}),
        port: DB_PORT,
        ssl: {
            ca: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem').toString(),
        },
    });

    await client.connect();
    await client.end();
})
```

So the certificate should be fine? I'm connecting to localhost:5432 which output a forwarded port on a jump server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems type-orm performs a stricter validation. To bypass it, I added `rejectUnauthorized` in the `extra` option:

```js
it("can connect using type-orm", async () => {
    const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
        type: "postgres",
        host: env.DB_HOST,
        port: env.DB_PORT,
        username: env.DB_USER,
        password: 'password123',
        database: env.DB_DATABASE,
        entities: [],
        synchronize: false,
        logging: false,
        ssl: {
            ca: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem').toString(),
        },
        extra: {
            ssl: {
                // Disregard mismatch between localhost and rds.amazonaws.com
                rejectUnauthorized: false 
            }
        }        
    })

    await AppDataSource.initialize()
});
```